# Display issues with android studio's emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm running android studio emulator and the display looks so unclear and everything like texts, icons, images look so "dotted" or sharp as in the images below.I don't understand what's causing this..how can I fix it? I'm running a GTX 960 and my display resolution is 1366x768

[image]

[image]

[image]

emulator properties here:

[image]

[image]

emulator.exe properties

[image]

Comment: can you send a snapshot of the properties of the emulator? or maybe even try creating a new emulator?

Comment: i tried creating a new emulator and everything was the same, i updated the thread with images of properties

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i'm using windows 10

Comment: Ok. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In windows/ubuntu, there are many issues with the emulator just like the one you mentioned.

Do the thing mentioned above

Go to your `\sdk\tools` location and find `emulator.exe`

Right click on `emulator.exe` and <kbd>properties</kbd> > <kbd>compatibility</kbd> =>check “Disable display scaling on high DPI settings” and click on apply...

Do the same thing with `emulator-x86.exe`

[image]

Now it will solve your low quality emulator problem

Comment: i don't have that option in the properties, i edited the thread with an image of what options i have

Comment: Why not check the first one in the second dialog of the image? Maybe that is the one its renamed to. In my case, the one I see is the one in the image